# @Autowired No qualifying bean of type - Bean extending Abstract class

Tags: spring, autowired

I have a bean in package - data.dao

```
@Component("questionDao")
@Transactional
public class QuestionDao extends AbstractDao<Question, Long>{

}
```

(all methods are implemented in AbstractDao)
I am writing testClass for this bean and I use autowiring like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="questionDao")
private QuestionDao questionDao;
```

This way it works without any problem!

Now I need to add very specific method for QuestionDao bean so I've change it a little bit:

```
@Component("questionDao")
@Transactional
public class QuestionDao extends AbstractDao<Question, Long>{
    public void doSomething(){
    }
}
```

As soon as I modify my bean (body is not empty) Autowiring doesnt work for some reason... "No qualifying bean of type data.dao.QuestionDao found for dependency. (I am using Spring 4.x)
Any ideas what can go wrong (In scenario 1 it works like charm but as soon as I touch QuestionDao class it fails to autowire)

Here's my AbstractDao class

```
public class AbstractDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements Dao<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Class<T> persistentClass;
    private Transaction transaction;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T findById(ID id) {
        transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();

        T object = (T) getSession().load(this.getPersistentClass(), id);

        transaction.commit();

        return object;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();

        List<T> list = this.findByCriteria();

        transaction.commit();

        return list;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) {
        Criteria crit = this.getSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass());

        for (Criterion c : criterion) {
            crit.add(c);
        }
        return (List<T>) crit.list();
    }

    @Override
    public T create(T entity) {
        transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();

        getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);

        transaction.commit();

        return entity;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T entity) {
        transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();

        getSession().delete(entity);

        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteTable() {
        transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();

        String deleteTable = new String ("delete " + this.getPersistentClass().getName());

        Query query = getSession().createQuery(deleteTable);
        query.executeUpdate();

        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Here's configuration for sessionFactory

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.dao</value>
                    <value>sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.entity</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Full stackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sk.uniza.fri.cuka.test.tests.AnswerDaoTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.dao.QuestionDao sk.uniza.fri.cuka.test.tests.AnswerDaoTest.questionDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.dao.QuestionDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=questionDao)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.dao.QuestionDao sk.uniza.fri.cuka.test.tests.AnswerDaoTest.questionDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.dao.QuestionDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=questionDao)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.dao.QuestionDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=questionDao)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 28 more
```

edit:
Problem solved: I just removed "@Transactional" and it works. I also refactor a little bit my QuestionDao so it implements interface as suggested Peter Jurkovic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a issue with Dao interface. Extract interface form your `QuestionDao` and it should works.

```
public interface QuestionDao extends Dao<Question, Long>{
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Create QuestionDaoImpl

```
@Transactional
@Repository("questionDao")
public class QuestionDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Question, Long> implements QuestionDao{
    public void doSomething(){
    }
}
```

Comment: I had it this way at first but I get the same error. I've just tried it again the way you show but i am getting still the same error, damn :(

Comment: Which AOP proxy mode have you been using? By annotation bean with `@Transactional` will be created proxy for given bean. BTW I also don't understand why you been using @Transactional when you managing transactions in your code. Does the QuestionDao bean was scanned  on application startup?

Comment: Well i am using Spring 4.1.7. and I am using default AOP proxy mode (i am newbie to Spring I didn't touch it at all). When I remove @Transactional it works. Thanks a lot. I guess I have to read some stuff about that annotation not sure why I was using it and why it was causing problems...

Comment: Did you ever find out why using @Transactional causes an issue?

Comment: @Tadhg Yes, It is because if you annotate a class with `@Transactional` will be created a proxy which "wrap" the class.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, now with your edit, I'm wondering if it might be due to the `@Autowired protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;` inside your abstract method that cannot be autowired. Do you have more info in your stacktrace? 
I'd try replacing it with a `@Autowired` setter or constructor.

something like this :

```
public class AbstractDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements Dao<T, ID> {

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public AbstractDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory= sessionFactory;
    }

///
}
```

Then you'll need to create a constructor in your QuestionDao too

---- not fixing the problem.

Try this :

```
@Component
@Transactional
@Qualifier("questionDao")
public class QuestionDao extends AbstractDao<Question, Long>{
    public void doSomething(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Hum, now with your edit, I'm wondering if it might be due to the ```@Autowired protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;``` inside your abstract method that cannot be autowired. Do you have more info in your  stacktrace? Can you try replacing it with a ```@Autowired``` setter or constructor ?

Comment: It's abstract class so I need to use setter however it's still not working for me. I am not sure how should I edit my QuestionDao (constructor you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

this exception is created by package scanning in components and add this xml configration file `<jpa:repositories base-package="sk.uniza.fri.cuka.data.dao"/>`